# updating Hive external table with HDFS changes

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

lets say, I created Hive external table "myTable" from file myFile.csv ( located in HDFS ).

myFile.csv is changed every day, then I'm interested to update "myTable" once a day too.

Is there any HiveQL query that tells to update the table every day?

Thank you.

P.S.

I would like to know if it works the same way with directories: lets say, I create Hive partition from HDFS directory "myDir", when "myDir" contains 10 files. next day "myDIr" contains 20 files (10 files were added). Should I update Hive partition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two types of tables in Hive basically.

One is Managed table managed by hive warehouse whenever you create a table data will be copied to internal warehouse.
You `can not have latest data in the query output`.

Other is external table in which hive `will not copy its data to internal warehouse`.

So whenever you fire query on table then it retrieves data from the file.

SO you can even have the latest data in the query output.

**`That is one of the goals of external table.`**

You can even drop the table and the data is not lost.

Comment: I would like to know if it works the same way with directories:

lets say, I create Hive partition from HDFS directory "myDir", when "myDir" contains 10 files.

next day "myDIr" contains 20 files (10 files were added).
Should I update Hive partition?

Answer (score 4):

If you add a `LOCATION '/path/to/myFile.csv'` clause to your table create statement, you shouldn't have to update anything in Hive.  It will always use the latest version of the file in queries.