# How to make a table that is automatically updated Hive

Tags: hive, hdfs, hiveql

I have created an external table that in Hive that uses data from a Parquet store in HDFS.

When the data in HDFS is deleted, there is no data in the table.  When the data is inserted again in the same spot in HDFS, the table does not get updated to contain the new data.  If I insert new records into the existing table that contains data, no new data is shown when I run my Hive queries.

How I create the table in Hive:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE nodes (id string) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION "/hdfs/nodes";
```

The relevant error:

```
Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /hdfs/nodes/part-r-00038-2149d17d-f890-48bc-a9dd-5ea07b0ec590.gz.parquet
```

I have seen several posts that explain that external tables should have the most up to date data in them, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027853/updating-hive-external-table-with-hdfs-changes).  However, this is not the case for me, and I don't know what is happening.

I inserted the same data into the database again, and queried the table.  It contained the same amount of data as before.  I then created an identical table with a different name.  It had twice as much data in it, which was the right amount.

The issue might be with the metastore database.  I am using PostgreSQL instead of Derby for the the database.

Relevant information:

- Hive 0.13.0
- Spark Streaming 1.4.1
- PostgreSQL 9.3
- CentOS 7

EDIT:
After examining the Parquet files, I found that the part files have seemingly incompatible file names.

`-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs   18702811 2015-08-27 08:22 /hdfs/nodes/part-r-00000-1670f7a9-9d7c-4206-84b5-e812d1d8fd9a.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs   18703029 2015-08-26 15:43 /hdfs/nodes/part-r-00000-7251c663-f76e-4903-8c5d-e0c6f61e0192.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs   18724320 2015-08-27 08:22 /hdfs/nodes/part-r-00001-1670f7a9-9d7c-4206-84b5-e812d1d8fd9a.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--   3 hdfs hdfs   18723575 2015-08-26 15:43 /hdfs/nodes/part-r-00001-7251c663-f76e-4903-8c5d-e0c6f61e0192.gz.parquet`

These files are the files that causes Hive to error when it can't find it in the error described above.  This means that the external table is not acting dynamically, accepting any files in the directory (if you call it that in HDFS), but instead is probably just keeping track of the list of parquet files inside the directory when it was created.

Sample Spark code:

    `nodes.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      if (!rdd.isEmpty())
        sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.map(
          n => Row(n.stuff), ParquetStore.nodeSchema)
          .write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(node_name)
    })`

Where the `nodeSchema` is the schema and `node_name` is "/hdfs/nodes"

See my other question about getting [Hive external tables to detect new files.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276177/can-a-hive-external-table-detect-new-parquet-files-in-hdfs)

Comment: if you drop the table and then you re-create it, what is happening?

Comment: I did a `select count(*) from nodes;', dropped the table, recreated the table, and redid the query.  Same result both times.

Comment: You state that "no new data is shown" -- like the Spark job is still writing into the files, they are less than 1 block long, so HDFS does not make them available to other processes like Hive. Then you mention an IOError *File does not exist* -- like Hive detected the file when setting up the Execution Plan, then some process just deleted the file before the actual execution (a background merge process for small Parquet files?! I'm not familiar with that format, but that's the way ORC deals with "transactions").

Comment: So it's not clear what is really happening, but it smells like an impedance mismatch between Spark, HDFS and Hive.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get Hive to update its tables, I had to resort to using the partitioning feature of Hive.  By creating a new partition during each Spark run, I create a series of directories internal to the `/hdfs/nodes` directory like this:

```
/hdfs/nodes/timestamp=<a-timestamp>/<parquet-files>
/hdfs/nodes/timestamp=<a-different-timestamp>/<parquet-files>
```

Then, after each Spark job completes, I run the Hive command `MSCK REPAIR TABLE nodes` using a `HiveContext` in my Spark job, which finds new partitions and updates the table.

I realize this isn't automatic, but it at least works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so probably you need to encapsulate the file in a folder. Hive external table must be mapped on a folder where there could be more than one file.

try to write the file to:  /path/to/hdfs/nodes/file
and then map the external table to /path/to/hdfs/nodes

so in the folder nodes you will have only the parquet file and it should works

Comment: I updated my question to indicate that I am doing what you suggested.  I believe that the issue is probably that, since I am writing multiple files to that directory EACH TIME I run my program, Hive probably only looks at the files that were in there when I first created the table.

Comment: could you post also the spark code ? I can't understand why hive is searching part data into the nodes directory.

Comment: Updated, but I believe I found a solution, if not really the answer to my question.

Comment: Just to be sure: that folder contains Parquet files, and nothing else (no sub-directory, no `SUCCESS__` flag, etc)? And all Parquet files have exactly the same structure, e.g. in the example shown, jobs *1670f7a9-blahblah* and *7251c663-blahblah* mapped the same columns in the same order?