# Can a Hive external table detect new Parquet files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am using Hive bundled with Spark.  My Spark Streaming job writes 250 Parquet files to HDFS per batch job, in the form of /hdfs/nodes/part-r-$partition_num-$job_hash.gz.parquet.  This means that after 1 job, I have 250 files in HDFS, and after 2, I have 500.  My external Hive table, created using Parquet, points at /hdfs/nodes for it's location, but it doesn't update to include the data in the new files after I rerun the program.

Do Hive external tables include new files in the table, or only updates to existing files that were there when the table was made?

Also see my related question about [automatically updating tables using Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235463/how-to-make-a-table-that-is-automatically-updated-hive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but I did eventually get Hive to detect new files using new partitions and `MSCK REPAIR TABLE tablename`, which detects the new partitions after they have been created.

This does not fix the original issue, as I have to create a new partition each time I have new files I want in Hive, but it has allowed me to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

You need to issue `REFRESH table_name` or `INVALIDATE METADATA [[db_name.]table_name]` command so Hive metadata are updated to include those new files.

This solution assumes you have Impala running.

Comment: Hmmm... Are you sure that these are *Hive* commands, not Impala-specific commands?

Comment: Since it's a Hive external table Impala can access the same metadata so this works.

Comment: So your answer is to use the *Impala* shell to run an *Impala* command, resulting in a reset of *Hive* metadata? Meaning that if he doesn't have the Cloudera distro he's stuck?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter If you have a solution using native Hive command, do share. Be constructive. I don't know Hive can automatically load new files to external table as opposite to append the a know file location, do you?

Comment: **(A)** my point was to check whether your solution has pre-requisites. If yes, it's important to mention them, because quite a lot of people on this planet don't use Cloudera distro **(B)** AFAIK Hive does *not* store a list of files in its MetaStore, just a list of directories; so the issue, as described, leaves me wondering what is actually happening (in the file generation process maybe)

Comment: (A) updated my answer to reflect the prerequisites. (B) Metadata contains things like IDs of DBs, Tables, and Indices among other things. So IMO Hive does keep track of data it has access to. I actually ran into the same problem before. I tried upload a file to Hive external table directory via Cloudera UI and HDFS command line. Hive does automatically include the new data to be searchable.

Comment: And I will not be using Impala, as the Hive I am using comes bundled with Spark

Comment: @zephyrthenoble It's fine you only want to use whatever Spark bundled with. But to remind you Spark works with Impala as well. Personally I prefer Impala for performance and usability. And Hive is the wrong architecture for real-time distributed SQL processing anyway.

Comment: @adam as we are running Hive queries as we run Spark jobs, and do not have a real-time constraint, I believe that Hive is the better choice.  Thank you for your information though.  if I ever need real-time processing, I will certainly look at Impala.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter maybe you can look at my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235463/how-to-make-a-table-that-is-automatically-updated-hive

Comment: @zephyrthenoble Impala is faster than Hive period. It doesn't have to be real-time application for Impala to be useful. Maybe it's just me who wants to run Spark job as fast as possible.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter just to clarify impala can be standalone deployment. It does not have to be deployed with CHD.

Comment: @adam: did you watch that presentation that starts with *"Impala states that it's faster than Hive. Fine. What isn't?"* and then proceeds with a comparison of Hive, SparkSQL, Presto, Impala, Hawq, etc etc etc >>> I don't judge how people choose their technology stack. The trick is to make it work in the first place; performance troubleshooting comes later.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter As I stated in my previous comment, it's fine if you only want to use Hive. I just want to run my Spark job as fast as possible and thought others would agree. I didn't watch that presentation because I already walked the talk. When I first learned Spark I used Hive too, it's just too slow for my dataset. So I turned to Impala. For me performance is not a after-thought in my design, it's necessary especially for big data analytic that can take hours to run. I just want to let you know that your statement about Impala is dependent on other Cloudera packages is false.